# Samsung Gear emulator hangs after clicking Power off

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-galaxy-gear

I'm developing an app for Samsung Gear 2 (using Tizen), the emulator is run from Tizen IDE. To power it off, I right click on the gear surface, then choose Close. Then a screen with 2 options "Power off" and "Restart" appears. I click "Power off", it just hangs there forever.

I tried another way: Right click the Gear surface. Then choose Advanced -> Force close. Still no luck. Do I miss any setup?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that I had another version of Intel HAXM installed before the one that comes with the tizen sdk package. Completely uninstall the old one before installing the package solved the problem.